# TypeORM-NestJs Join on Json column

Tags: mysql, typescript, inner-join, nestjs, typeorm

join two mysql tables using typeorm-NestJs
where `table 1(t1)` is normal table
& `table 2(t2)` has a column which containts JSON data

now I need to join them based on `t1.id == t2.column_name.id`

but I am getting error on that query

query I am using :-

```
const results  = await this.connection.createQueryBuilder(ABCEntity,'t1')
    .innerJoinAndMapMany('t1.Id',xyzEntity,'t2','t1.Id = t2.column_name.$.Id')
    .where('t1.Id = :Id',{Id: id})
    .getMany()
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Error I am getting :-

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.Id WHERE `t1`.`Id` = 'b6D812aF-9e22-4a5a-a292-6rc5021bfv0a'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
```

Comment: `t2.column_name.$.Id` is incorrect, try `t2.column_name->'$.Id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me was, everything in backticks
for eg : `t1.Id = t2.column_name->'$.Id'

```
const results  = await this.connection.createQueryBuilder(ABCEntity,'t1')
.innerJoinAndMapMany('t1.Id',xyzEntity,'t2',`t1.Id = t2.column_name->'$.Id'`)
.where('t1.Id = :Id',{Id: id})
.getMany()
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I have a similar setup with the same error. `leftJoinAndMapOne`. Backticks arent making a difference, do you have any other advice?